# how do I add multiple case when conditions in mysql/presto?

Tags: sql, presto

consider the following function

```
Row_Number() over(
        partition by id
        order by case
                category
                when 'HIGH' then 1
                when 'MEDIUM' then 2
                when 'LOW' then 3
            end
    )
```

why does replacing the first case with `when 'HIGH' or 'VERY HIGH' then 1` cause this error and how to get around this

```
Left side of logical expression must evaluate to a boolean (actual: varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because how [`CASE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html?#case) works. Options are:

- "duplicate values"

```sql
case category
     when 'HIGH' then 1
     when 'VERY HIGH' then 1
     when 'MEDIUM' then 2
     when 'LOW' then 3
end
```

- use expression-less syntax:

```sql
case 
     when category in ('HIGH', 'VERY HIGH') then 1
     when category = 'MEDIUM' then 2
     when category = 'LOW' then 3
end
```